# Xamarin SQLite db connections issue

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, dbconnection

I am trying to connect my xamarin app with SQLite, everything seems fine but in App.xaml.cs i get the following error: ***System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'***

This is how my App.xaml.cs page looks like:

```
using System;
using TestAppDemo.Services;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace TestAppDemo
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnectionWithCreateDatabase();
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help? Do I need to provide you with more information?

Thanks!

Comment: Which specific line throws the exception?  What does the stack trace show?  Finally, using DependencyService with SQLite should not be needed - at one time it was, but newer versions of SQLite.net do not require it.

Comment: @Jason this line gives exception:             DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnectionWithCreateDatabase();

Comment: There are two statements in that line, which one is causing it?

Comment: Break it up into two lines and figure out which one causes it.  Or look at the stack trace.  This is basic C# debugging